# Signal called in settings importing an app : failed

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am using `Python 3.4.3`, `Django 1.9.2` and `django-haystack 2.4.1`.

I only put the essential code to explain.

**Here is my settings :**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    contacts.documents,
    haystack,
    contacts.search,
)

HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'contacts.search.signals.MyRealtimeProcessor'
```

**Here is my file : contacts.search.signals.py :**

```
from contacts.documents.models import Document

class MyRealtimeProcessor(RealtimeSignalProcessor):

    def handle_save(self, sender, instance, **kwargs):
        …
        d_index = self.connections[using].get_unified_index()\
                                                 .get_index(Document)
```

With this code I obtain **the error** :

```
 raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
```

Because of `from contacts.documents.models import Document` in my signal.

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load models before Django has finished loading all apps. It's not entirely clear to me why your `signals.py` file is being imported before the apps are loaded, but you can get around this by moving this logic into the `__init__` method of your class:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from contacts.documents.models import Document

    self.document_model = Document
    super(MyRealtimeProcessor, self).__init__(args, kwargs)
```

and then in `handle_save`:

```
d_index = self.connections[using].get_unified_index()\
                                             .get_index(self.document_model)
```